From what movie/serie is this story?
I've been trying to remember where a story, I had on my mind since some months, is from. 
Release time: I can't remember when exactly it was released, but it probably must be from the last years, since it is a new topic. I'm sure it is an American show.
The story: The main character is going after an terrorist group, who are some kind of hackers (I think they do violent things too, I'm not sure). The leader is a black man who wants revenge for his brother, who got tagged as terrorist because tutoring a muslim man whose cousin was a the real terrorist. He went unfairly to jail and commited suicide there. The American goverment didn't want to tell the truth to the brother, plus the death of his brother made him the leader of that group. Also they got to choose their members, like this leader, who was chosen because of his story (in the start he didn't want to join them).
Maybe it can be an episode of a series or a movie. 
Genre: action (?)

You're describing a story arc in Person of Interest that happens in the last few episode of season 3, about the terrorist/hackers group called Vigilance and their leader Peter Collier
You can find a long detailed information about both in the last 2 links above, but here's a couple parts that match your description:


his brother is not being charged with anything but is also not allowed to speak with a lawyer. Peter insists in telling that they have arrested the wrong person. The attorney shows him several pictures of Jesse taken from surveillance footage that shows him with Aziz Al-Ibrahim, whose cousin was part of a terrorist group.
Jesse (his brother) has passed away, supposedly committing suicide


